# Selected Index of Dropdownlist?

Tags: drop-down-menu

how shall I set the selected index of the dropdownlist in this function .

please tell me?

```
public IList GetMountainList()
    {
        int mountainId = 0;
        string mountainName = string.Empty;

        using (brandconnectionsEntities modelObject = new brandconnectionsEntities())
        {
            return (IList)(from s in modelObject.BC_mountainResortMediaList
                                          select new 
                                          {

                                              mountainId = s.mountainResortId,
                                              mountainName = s.mountainResortName,
                                              SelectExtensions = s.mountainResortId ,
                                          })
              .ToList();
        }
    }
```

Thanks
Ritz

Comment: How is this question different from the others you have already posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175883/dropdownlist-in-mvc and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190240/dropdownlist-problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Language and Gui library information would be nice for everyone :)